# Why doesn't NoMatch render

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Bjorgvin/pen/vmWpXP) that is based on [React Router Template](https://codepen.io/ReactJSTraining/pen/jyYjeW) that shows how a *NoMatch* component is not rendered even if you go to a URL that has no match in the router configuration.

When I move the *NoMatch* `Route` into `AboutTopicsRoute` it works fine. However, I don't want it there since my application might grow and there are different routes in different files and it gets confusing to move the *NoMatch* around just so it renders correctly.

Is it a bug in React-Router or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have nested 'Switch'

If you change from

```
const AboutTopicsRoute = (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
  </Switch> 
)
```

to

```
const AboutTopicsRoute = (

    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>

)
```

Then `no-match` route works again